# Android : How to load a custom ROM without SD-card

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, adb, rom-flashing

I have an Asus TF-201(rooted), on which I would like to install Android. I have downloaded the Cyanogenmod ROM/OS, which is in a ZIP file(200Mb), contains files like boot.blob, system.new.dat(405.9mb), etc.

I have copied the zip file in a Pen-drive and the pen-drive is plugged in on keyboard of its Dock. After that, I booted into the recovery mode by CWM, but when I say mount SD-Card, it says, cannot mount SD-card.

I also cannot find the option of exploring the internal-storage in recovery to point the location of ROM.zip. What should I do?

Next thing I tried was to sideload as I have a UBuntu system running which can recognize the tablet. As soon as I start the sideload command, I don't see any progress or anything, the command just waits with a blinking cursor, waited for 1 hour and pressed `ctrl+c`.

So, now I have a ROM image sitting on my tablet, but no way to boot into it. Can anyone help me with booting from it. Please note, the memory-card slot is damaged.

Is there any way to get to trigger the installation? Kindly let me know. Thank you.

*Update*

This is what I see :

[image]

Comment: In CWM there is an option *Install Zip*. Go into it and  you would be shown a  list with available storage as the options. Are you saying you're not getting that option?

Comment: There was a CyanogenMod Installer. But I think it was cancelled due being dangerous somehow. Might wanna check that - on your own risk of course.

Comment: @Firelord : When I click on choose zip from sdcard, it says E:Can't mount /sdcard/

Comment: What other options do you see there?

Comment: @Firelord : I updated the post to show what I see.. I see myself as well :D

Comment: @WeareBorg Can you try [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/asustransformerprimeTF201.html)? Your CWM version is too old?

Comment: @Firelord : Should I uninstall CWM from the tablet. Also, I made a mistake, my tablet is tf101, not tf201. I will update the main post, and have already downloaded ROM for that. Right now I am installing TWRP manager from play-store. Correct?

Comment: I prefer [flashing from fastboot](https://twrp.me/devices/asustransformerTF101.html) but you can try with app and see if it works. The current recovery will be overwritten.

Comment: @Firelord : That TWRP thing didn't fly, I tell him to select zip, I mark two of them, Gapps and the ROM, it selects nothing. Uploading image. Can you please come on chat.#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36172/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-firelord).